# PHP parse without replacing

Tags: php, parsing

I have seen some parsing code that's really long, but it doesn't involve replacing stuff inside an opened file using `file_get_contents()` for example. I'm talking about say parsing a `.doc` into `.html` format. They read the file and then output it in html. I have tried this using arrays and `preg_replace`, but it just doesn't seem as clean as other code. Anyone know the basic concept of parsing? Thanks, tell me if im not clear.

Edit: Lets say I have this from a doc or rtf file: \b text \b

That would need to be converted to `<strong>text</strong>`. Others do it without `preg_replace` or `str_replace` and stuff, almost as if they build the new page somehow.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to "converting" a .doc into a .html file? That's not considered parsing. For something like that, try looking at [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/).